# How to add a flask app to my Wordpress website

Tags: python, wordpress, flask, web, plugins

I have embedded an AI Chatbot (using Python)in a flask application
Now I want to add this application to my Wordpress website .
Is there a possible way to integrate the application in Wordpress.

What I tried:
I tried to create a plugin but I couldn't convert the Flask application to a plugin in Wordpress
What I expected :
A way to add the flask app(Chatbot) to my Wordpress website

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.